# "Dragging" Sound Effect with iOS Sprite-Kit

Tags: ios, swift, audio, sprite-kit

Developing a Sprite Kit (in swift) based game for iOS.
I need to have a sound effect play while the player drags an object across the screen. Not sure how to "prepare" the sound file for it to have a "start" and "end" but a "looping" duration during the drag itself. The challenge, among the many, is the fact that the sound of something being dragged is not easily created as a loop.

Any advice?

Comment: Use AVAudioPlayer. Set it to loop. Start and stop it based on touchesBegan and touchesEnded.

Comment: ObjectAL is a great library for doing this kind of stuff too.

Comment: first, thanks for the help.
a follow-up question:

do you think it would be possible to have a single sound file for the start, lop and end of the effect?

let me explain:
the sound of dragging an object as a distinct beginning and end.
could i launch the sound the sound, to get the "start" of the sound, then loop the "middle" of the sound and then when the user STOPS dragging, instantly SEEK to the end to play the "end" of the sound?

possible?

Comment: Any more ideas? Still stuck...!